# Thought experiment. Earth orbital motion if we stopped Earth spinning

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy

This is a thought experiment that puzzles me. Imagine we could magically stop Earth’s rotation around its own axis (and locally verify it by disappearance of inertial forces generated by the spin alone) and only alow it to continue its orbital movement. 
How would this movement look? Would Earth keep facing the Sun with one side (rotation about the Sun’s axis, Earth Sun orientation locked as if with a string between them) or would this motion be a translation(not rotation) along the orbital path (Earth keeping constant orientation relative to distant stars, like moving a flat picture along a circle without changing the angle )?
Ignore influence of other bodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast to linear movement rotation is absolute. So if the Earth would not rotate, it would always keep the same orientation with respect to the distant stars and galaxies. Because if its motion around the Sun a day would last a whole year.

Tidal effects can dissipate rotational energy but the end result not zero rotation. It is rotational lockin. In such a case the rotating object always faces the object it rotates about with the same side. The Earth's moon is in this state.

Comment: That's fascinating and a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: That's fascinating and a bit counter intuitive to me...but must be right ;).  Does it also mean that when a satellite is injected into Earth's orbit (assuming  ideal linear thrust as the only force) its spin is zero and therefore its orientation towards stars is fixed around the orbit? I always assumed the satellite's orientation was fixed relative to the direction of the centripetal/gravity forces.

Comment: @MaxSense satellites do what their owner wants them to do. Earth-observing and communication satellites usually have a rotation that matches their orbital period so that they can stay pointing "down". Other stuff may not.

Comment: @hobbs Yes, I understand that now. I was under impression thought that the pure orbital motion was geometrically described by rotation about the point in space (e.g. satellite rotating around the Earth) but I'm learning this is not the case. Instead I'm being told that motion really is described by translation along the orbital path (no change of angle v. distant stars). Is this correct?
I'm just trying to decouple in my mind mechanisms and understand what part of motion and orientation stems purely from the balance between gravity and centripetal force and the initial velocity vector.

Comment: @MaxSense yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Simple-mindedly it would initially retain its zero spin, so the day would be a year long and the Sun would move from west to east.  Over time it would become tidally locked to the Sun and would turn only one face to it.

In real life I expect things would be much more complicated: The Moon and other bodies in the Solar System (which I think means 'Jupiter' to a pretty good approximation) would perturb things significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If the earth stops its rotation around its axis, many sorts of interesting things happen. Firstly what you want to know, the Earth would not face the Sun with only one face because that needs some rotation around it's axis. Just like the moon faces the Earth with always one hemisphere because its rotation around its axis has the same period as its translation around the Earth. In your thought experiment, a day would last a year! In other words the light of the Sun would fall in different parts of the Earth as it moves around the Sun. Equally different parts of the Earth would see the night at some point, however they would be missing parts of the night sky, because if you are in some part of the Earth the night always comes in a specific portion of the year and you would never see half of the night sky. But you could travel to different parts of the world to see the other portion of night sky you are missing. Also, seasons would coincide with specific parts of the day: at midday it would always be summer, for a couple of months, then as the Sun closes in to sunset weather would turn colder to Autumn, reaching Winter in the night and turning to Spring as the Sun rises again. But the Summers would not be similar all over the world because the portions of the Earth where midday falls when the Earth is closer would experience a much hotter Summer, while those on midday when the Earth is farthest would experience a milder Summer.  The Winters though might not differ except for duration, since the Earth's orbit around the Sun is not circular, but elliptical and the Earth moves faster when is closer to the Sun than when it is farther away.I am sure there are many other interesting aspects, especially for biology, but I don't know enough. My guess is that most animals for survival would need to be constantly migrating to stay always in the twilight zones, where weather is more stable a adequate, since the daylight/night zones would be either excessively hot or unbearably cold for life. Tornadoes and hurricanes would probably not occur because of the Coriolis forces would disappear with the lack of Earth's rotation, but some type of air/water currents should occur in the twilight areas. That would make a nice science fiction scenario, and a nice title "Twilight lands" or something of the sort.